# Security - Use Active Directory or SQL Server and Why?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, sql-server-2012

My company is currently planning to reconfigure security and we are currently arguing over which way to go, storing everything in Active Directory or in SQL Server?
So setting up Active Directory groups and use it to create a read and a read/write group and just move users in and out of these security groups and manage security for SQL Server from Active Directory or use SQL Server and move all users into security and create groups in SQL Server and manage the
security from there?

Comment: you'd be better off asking this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ as this doesn't directly involve programming in any way. possibly even http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AD is the way to go in my opinion, for a number of reasons.

Security doesn't just cover access to databases. It covers access to files, folders etc. Anything in SQL is irrelevant to the question 'Should they have access to this spreadsheet?'. AD is the way to go there. Why not integrate everything into the same mechanism?

AD is more flexible than SQL. An AD Group can contain other AD groups. If you have an AD group called e.g. 'Power Traders' then the Power Traders are added to that group. There would also be groups which give access to individual securables (files, folders, databases, apps etc); 'Power Traders' would be added to those groups and inherit the access to the individual things. If another job also needs access to one of these, that job group can be added to the necessary individual group.

If an individual needs access to something outside his normal job, just add them to the individual groups necessary.

A full solution would actually have multiple levels of groups. How many would be down to the company and how it wishes to organise itself.